# C++ Performance of one list

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list

I created one template class, and I did a `removeMiddle` method like this:

```
template <typename T> void List<T>::removeMiddle(int pos){

((getNodeAt(pos)->next)->prev) = (getNodeAt(pos)->prev);

((getNodeAt(pos)->prev)->next) = (getNodeAt(pos)->next);

delete getNodeAt(pos);
}
```

The method `getNodeAt(int)` runs the list and returns a specific node you want.

Can what I did cause loss of performance in my app, or not?
Because I would like to do this:

```
template <typename T> void List<T>::removeMiddle(int pos){

node *aux = getNodeAt(pos);

(aux->next)->prev = aux->prev;
(aux->prev)->next = aux->next;

 delete aux;
}
```

Is the second method faster than first?

Comment: Do you actually need a linked list?  The performance characteristics of a linked list is rarely optimal.  Are you performance testing optimized code or unoptimized code?  What does the body of `getNodeAt` look like?

Comment: i'm practicing what i learned on college, and improving my skills too, and thats tha body of getNodeAt(int)

Comment: If you want to judge performance you should test it.  Some things are obvious, but if it is not obvious (to you) what will perform well and what will not you need to test it.

Comment: Thanks  for the replies, i understood. ^^

Answer (score 5):

**Don't even worry about performance until you've dealt with correctness.**  That can't possibly be repeated enough.

The first method is wrong; you're deallocating the wrong node.  The node you want to delete is no longer in the list and can't be found by `getNodeAt(pos)`.

The fact that the second implementation is faster as well as correct is just a nice bonus.  Being correct is what counts.

EDIT: This might be slightly better:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::removeMiddle( int const pos )
{
    assert(pos >= 0);
    if (pos == 0) { removeHead(); return; }

    node * const pred = getNodeAt(pos - 1); // what happens if pos == 0 ??
    node * const target = pred->next;
    node * const succ = target->next;

    if (!succ) { removeTail(); return; }

    succ->prev = pred;
    pred->next = succ;
    delete target;
}
```

Comment: the node 0 is the first node on the list

Comment: @Kleber: Right, and then what is `getNodeAt(0)->prev`?

Comment: I used the returned node as a node itself, so i call the previous node using the getNodeAt(0)->prev.

Comment: well, i think getNodeAt(0), not exist, it is NULL ( nullptr), i had not thought about it, it is an error, or not, I'm passing the NULL (nullptr) for the "prev" of the next node. Oh now i'm confused, i don't even know waht i'm talking about ashuahus

Comment: @Kleber: Ok, added handling for end-cases, so the code won't end up dereferencing a NULL pointer.